# Prove spatial velocity identity - screw theory

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, transformation

This question involves a proof regarding coordinate transformations of velocities of screw motions. This comes from "A Mathematical Introduction to Robotic Manipulation" (the text is available for free here: http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/MLS/pdf/mls94-complete.pdf)

The identity is shown below, and is on pg. 59 of the above link. Here's the image:

[image: The identity to prove]

I know how to get $V_{a,c}^c$ (with respect to frame c). That comes directly from the chain rule, switching the order of $\dot{g}$ and $g^{-1}$. But I don't know how to get $V_{a,c}^b$ (with respect to frame b), i.e. the left-hand side.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please, use a notation consistent with one from the book, without “(superscript c)” verbosities that might suggest “I pay reps and won’t spend my time for this chaff”. Read e.g. at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference how to make subscripts and superscripts with MathJax; HTML tags are permitted as well.

Comment: Gave it a go, but I'm having trouble with "g_dot"

Comment: FYI, doing "\dot{g}" gives $\dot{g}$

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks guys for helping me prepare for the eventual thesis done in Latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of 2.15 is more or less the same as proof of 2.14 as stated.

Let's start with definition of $V_{ac}^b$
$$
V^b_{ac} = g^{-1}_{ac}\dot g_{ac}
$$
Now substitute $g_{ac} = g_{ab}g_{bc}$ and $g^{-1}_{ac}= g^{-1}_{bc}g^{-1}_{ab}$.
\begin{align}
V^b_{ac} &= g^{-1}_{bc}g^{-1}_{ab} \dot{\overline{ g_{ab}g_{bc}}}  \\
&= g^{-1}_{bc}g^{-1}_{ab} \left( \dot g_{ab}g_{bc} + g_{ab}\dot g_{bc}\right) \\
&=  g^{-1}_{bc}\left(g^{-1}_{ab} \dot g_{ab}\right)g_{bc} + g^{-1}_{bc} \dot g_{bc} \\
&= Ad_{g^{-1}_{bc}} V^b_{ab} + V^b_{bc}
\end{align}

I hope it is clear.

(Just in case: The overdot overline notation means $\dot{\overline{ g_{ab}g_{bc}}}= \frac{d}{dt}\left(g_{ab}g_{bc}\right)$. The bar is useful to indicate what has to be differentiated, only the dot would be confusing.)

---

In the text there is no meaning given to the symbol $V^c$ but only to $V^b$(velocity in body frame) and $V^s$ (velocity in global frame).

---

I'll try to explain how to think about screw motions and what is the diffference between . We can explain this quite easily with **rotations**.

Let's have two coordinate frames $A,B \in SO(3)$. The *fastest* way to transform $A$ to $B$ is by rotation $g_{ab}$ around some [great circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle). You might be familiar with [slerp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp), that is the way how to calculate this rotation. Velocity is just vector perpendicular to that great circle. You can express it the spatial(world) frame or in the rotating(body) frame, which is rotating from frame $A$ to the frame $B$. What is quite peculiar is that when you express velocity in the body frame, which is moving, the coordinates of velocity stays the same. In fact only vectors parallel to the velocity vector has constant coordinates in body frame. All other vectors, not parallel to velocity, expressed in body frame change in time.

Rotations around great circles are the same to the $SO(3)$ as screw motions to the $SE(3)$. So screw motions are just generalization of above so except changing orientation you can change position too.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. What's not clear to me is this notion of "body" frame versus "spatial" frame. I thought frame A was spatial, b and c are different body frames. Does $V^b$, velocity in body frame, refer to frame b or c then?

Comment: Right now I do not know how to explain properly body and spatial frame. But $A,B,C$ are just some frames and $g_{ab}$ is screw motion between $A,B$, $V_{ab}$ is "velocity" of hypothetical body undergoing screw motion $g_{ab}$ and the "velocity" can be given in spatial frame $V^s_{ab}$ or in body frame $V^b_{ab}$ of that hypothetical body.

Comment: I'll think on it some more. Thanks again tom.

Comment: So $V^b_{bc}$ does not refer to the frame $B$ neither $C$. It is velocity(in body frame) of body undergoing screw motion $g_{bc}$.

Comment: @JDS How much are you familiar with Lie groups and lie algebras? So I know how much jargon I can use and not to confuse you? Are you ok with groups $SO(3),SE(3)$, algebras $so(3),se(3)$, exponential map(in the context of lie group!) etc.?

Comment: Those terms are fine. I'm an engineer, so I'm trying to think of "spatial" and "body" in terms of parts of a robot.. Like the spatial frame being a "base" (stationary mount) and a body frame perhaps as an end-effector (hand) frame. So you're saying $V_{bc}$, if in the body frame, would be the velocity of the body through the transformation $g_{bc}$? I can understand that. Seems sort of abstract though.

Comment: I modified my answer. I tried to explain body and spatial velocity just for rotations. Where it is quite clear what it means. I'm not that familiar with screw motions, but they have to work similar way, because the math do.